# User scan the poster using hololens. 3D Content will overlay on the poster

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

In editor content overlay on poster working fine. But when I build and run in HoloLens,the position of the 3d model is not proper, it is not stable.

I enable extended tracking and tried.

Software versions:

```
    Unity3d:2018.1.0f2
    Vuforia : HoloLens vuforia 7.1.34
    HoloToolKit:HoloToolKit_unity_2017.4.0.0-rc.
```

Enable  Capabilities:

```
   WebCam, Spatial Perception, Microphone
```

Comment: Your poster is likely a bad target. How many stars did Vuforia give it? You want 4 or 5.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the hololens camera isn't great, you should expect worse results than most desktop webcams.

Comment: I got 5 star rating for my marker.Is there any other way to superimpose 3d model on top of the real object(Instead of marker).